# Can't derefence variable so function is satisfied

Tags: c, gcc, casting, dereference

I can't seem to run this function called factorial() without getting an error.

At first if I have `inbuf = atoi(factorial(inbuf));`, gcc will spit out,

```
main.c:103: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘factorial’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

If I change it to `inbuf = atoi(factorial(inbuf*));`, gcc will spit out,

```
main.c:103: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
```

Relevant code:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int temp;

    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return temp = n * factorial(n - 1);
} // end factorial

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *inbuf[MSGSIZE];
    int fd[2];

    # pipe() code
    # fork() code

    // read the number to factorialize from the pipe
    read(fd[0], inbuf, MSGSIZE);

    // close read
    close(fd[0]);

    // find factorial using input from pipe, convert to string
    inbuf = atoi(factorial(inbuf*));

    // send the number read from the pipe to the recursive factorial() function
    write(fd[1], inbuf, MSGSIZE);

    # more code

} // end main
```

What am I missing about dereferencing and my syntax??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rearrange your calls on this line:

```
inbuf = atoi(factorial(inbuf*));
```

should be

```
int answ = factorial(atoi(inbuf));
```

*Assuming all the other code works, but I think you need to change the declaration of inbuf from `char *inbuf[MSGSIZE];` to `char inbuf[MSGSIZE];`

Comment: That gives me "main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:103: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/stdlib.h:148: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
main.c:103: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[15]’ from type ‘int’"

Comment: see my edit about changing the declaration, char* inbuf[MSGSIZE] gives you an array of character pointers, you just want an array of characters

Comment: Hmm, starting to make sense. I'm receiving "lab6.c:103: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[15]’ from type ‘int’" now which has to do with the fact that factorial is returning int to inbuf which is expecting char[15], hense why I had atoi() on the outside of factorial(). Anyway, you answered my original question and it is very _very_ much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: whoops, missed that.  You should have the final result of the factorial stored in an int then convert it into another string (character array) if you need it in that format.

Answer (score 1):

First, change *inbuf* to: `char inbuf[MSGSIZE];`

Second, you need to convert *inbuf* to *int* to pass it to `factorial()`. `atoi()` does exactly that. Then, you grab the result of this operation and convert it back to a string and assign it to *inbuf*: that's why `sprintf()` does.

```
// find factorial using input from pipe, convert to string
sprintf(inbuf, "%d", factorial(atoi(inbuf)));
```

Comment: This is exactly how I ended up doing it. Thank you. I'm keep the check mark for 'DShook', only because I used his advise and ran with it, but technically, you solved my entire problem, not just the problem with atoi(). Thank you.